# Returning Longest from Array with 1 Parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, parameters

Similar questions have been asked but i haven't found one that helps my problem....I am wanting to create a function that takes one parameter an returns the longest string in an array and if 2 are same length returns the first one in the string. I am sure that i will need a for loop and such, but i am getting nowhere and the code i have is not good but i am posting for your consideration:

```
     function longestString([strs]) {
       var strs = ["afrec" "aaa", "tummdor"];
       var lgth = 0;
       var longest;
       for (var i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        if strs[i].length > lgth) {
          var lgth = strs[i].length;
          longest = strs[i];
        }

      }
      return longest;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Array `reduce()` Method.

The `reduce()` method reduces the array to a single value. This method executes a provided function for each value of the array. The return value of the function is stored in an accumulator (result/total).

```js
var strs = [ 'afrec', 'aaa', 'tummdor' ];

var longest = strs.reduce( function( a, b ) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b
}, '');

console.log( 'Longest string is: ' + longest )
```

Comment: So sorry i haven't responded to you soon to say thank you, i just logged on to research a different question and discovered your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array using `.sort()` and then return the very first value of array.

```js
let longestString = a => a.sort((s1, s2) => s2.length - s1.length)[0];

console.log(longestString(["afrec", "aaa", "tummdor", "summdar"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw your code should work apart from few syntax errors:

```
function longestString(strs) {
   var lgth = 0;
   var longest;
   for (var i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    if (strs[i].length > lgth) {
      lgth = strs[i].length;
      longest = strs[i];
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

console.log(longestString(["afrec", "aaa", "tummdssssssor", "adadadadadad"]));
```

Comment: Code only answers will not help. Please try explaining why the solution best works and what could be the reason behind the issue.